# Group of rows in column in SQL Server or C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2014 and .NET 4.5, programming in C#.

I am importing an Excel sheet which has some dynamic columns with respective data and saving into the database. So far, I was successful, but some data showing in grid I am getting a problem.

Import data screen:

[image]

i try some thing but not success

> ```
>     // select FieldName,FieldValue from AttImportDetail where AttImportID =1
>     private DataTable GenerateTransposedTable(DataTable inputTable)
>     {
>         DataTable outputTable = new DataTable();
>         DataTable distinct = inputTable.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "FieldName"); // get unique column name
>         int Columns = distinct.Rows.Count; // get unique column count 
>         int rows = inputTable.Rows.Count / distinct.Rows.Count; // count no of rows
>         //  create datatable with unique column name 
>         foreach (DataRow inRow in distinct.Rows)
>         {
>             string newColName = inRow[0].ToString();
>             outputTable.Columns.Add(newColName);
>         }
>         // add data
>         for (int i = 0; i < inputTable.Rows.Count; i++)
>         {
>             DataRow newRow = outputTable.NewRow();
>             for (int c = 0; c < outputTable.Columns.Count; c++)
>             {
>                 string colValue = inputTable.Rows[i][c].ToString();
>                 string FieldName  = inputTable.Rows[i][c].ToString();
>                  newRow[FieldName] = colValue;
>             }
>             outputTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
>         }
>         return outputTable;
>     }
> ```

Data is saved into the database. till `totalPh` is one record after that next record start:

[image]

expecting result

[image]

some help available on this site [enter link description here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44274/Transpose-a-DataTable-using-C)

Comment: Do you really just have 2 select statements? or did you mean to link them together? looking at the sql you got exactly what you asked for.

Comment: From the data that you shown above , example for Attimportid = 1, you have 2 row of FieldName = 2, one with FieldValue K and another H, how do you identify which belongs to which empcode ?

Comment: What have you tried yourself? This is not a code writing service.

Comment: i am getting problem here each 32 rows is on one row, how to bring in column of each group rows

Answer (score 0):

Hmm you can try something like this:
(Solution on the SQL side)

```
--drop cached TempCacheTable if exists and create new
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempCacheTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TempCacheTable;
CREATE TABLE [#TempCacheTable] ( [Index] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL ) 

DECLARE @fName nvarchar(30), @val nvarchar(30);
DECLARE @columns nvarchar(max) = '', @col nvarchar(max) = '', @sql varchar(max) = '', @valStr nvarchar(max) = '';
DECLARE @first bit = 1, @counter int = 0;

--create cursor to loop through @TempTable
        DECLARE Column_Cur CURSOR
            FOR SELECT FieldName, FieldValue FROM AttImportDetail WHERE AttImportID = 1;

            OPEN Column_Cur;
                FETCH NEXT FROM Column_Cur INTO @fName, @val;
                    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                    BEGIN

                        --set the dynamic column
                        IF @first = 1 BEGIN                         
                            SET @col = '[' + @fName + '] nvarchar(20)';
                            SET @columns = '[' + @fName + ']';
                            SET @valStr = @val;
                            SET @first = 0;
                        END ELSE BEGIN                          
                            SET @col = @col + ', [' + @fName + '] nvarchar(20)';
                            SET @columns = @columns + ', ' + '[' + @fName + ']';
                            SET @valStr = @valStr + ', ' + @val;
                        END

                        -- or you can filter by column name
                        IF @fName = 'TotalP' BEGIN
                          --  SET @col = @col + ', [' + @fName + '] int';
                        END                                         

                      -- break cursor after all 12 columns
                       IF @counter = 12 BEGIN
                          BREAK;
                       END
                        SET @counter = @counter + 1;                    

                        FETCH NEXT FROM Column_Cur INTO @fName, @val;
                    END

            CLOSE Column_Cur;
        DEALLOCATE Column_Cur;    

SELECT @sql = 'ALTER TABLE #TempCacheTable ADD ' + @col
--execute to apply the change to #TempCacheTable
EXEC(@sql);    


SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO #TempCacheTable (' + @columns + ') VALUES (' + @valStr + '); 
SELECT * FROM #TempCacheTable;';
EXEC(@sql);

--drop cached TempCacheTable if exists and create new
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempCacheTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TempCacheTable;
```

In case you want the Column Row to stop after TotalPH. Than stop this cursor after it comes to the TotalPH column.
Apply the columns, and create a second cursor with wich you collect the value data and insert it into the TempCacheTable after each row ends on TotalPH. Than it will list it like you want.

Here is the new updated working code sample:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (
    AttImportID int,
    FieldName nvarchar(20),
    FieldValue nvarchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (AttImportID, FieldName, FieldValue) VALUES (1, 'EmbCode', 'FA160620');
INSERT INTO @temp (AttImportID, FieldName, FieldValue) VALUES (1, '1', 'PH');
INSERT INTO @temp (AttImportID, FieldName, FieldValue) VALUES (1, '2', 'K');
INSERT INTO @temp (AttImportID, FieldName, FieldValue) VALUES (1, '3', 'P');
INSERT INTO @temp (AttImportID, FieldName, FieldValue) VALUES (1, '4', 'P');
INSERT INTO @temp (AttImportID, FieldName, FieldValue) VALUES (1, '5', 'WO');
INSERT INTO @temp (AttImportID, FieldName, FieldValue) VALUES (1, '6', 'P');
INSERT INTO @temp (AttImportID, FieldName, FieldValue) VALUES (1, '7', 'P');
INSERT INTO @temp (AttImportID, FieldName, FieldValue) VALUES (1, '8', 'P');
INSERT INTO @temp (AttImportID, FieldName, FieldValue) VALUES (1, '9', 'P');
INSERT INTO @temp (AttImportID, FieldName, FieldValue) VALUES (1, '10', 'P');
INSERT INTO @temp (AttImportID, FieldName, FieldValue) VALUES (1, 'TotalP', '18');
INSERT INTO @temp (AttImportID, FieldName, FieldValue) VALUES (1, 'TotalPH', '0,5');
INSERT INTO @temp (AttImportID, FieldName, FieldValue) VALUES (1, 'EmbCode', 'FA160621');
INSERT INTO @temp (AttImportID, FieldName, FieldValue) VALUES (1, '1', 'P');
INSERT INTO @temp (AttImportID, FieldName, FieldValue) VALUES (1, '2', 'H');
INSERT INTO @temp (AttImportID, FieldName, FieldValue) VALUES (1, '3', 'P');
INSERT INTO @temp (AttImportID, FieldName, FieldValue) VALUES (1, '4', 'WO');
INSERT INTO @temp (AttImportID, FieldName, FieldValue) VALUES (1, '5', 'WO');
INSERT INTO @temp (AttImportID, FieldName, FieldValue) VALUES (1, '6', 'K');
INSERT INTO @temp (AttImportID, FieldName, FieldValue) VALUES (1, '7', 'P');
INSERT INTO @temp (AttImportID, FieldName, FieldValue) VALUES (1, '8', 'PH');
INSERT INTO @temp (AttImportID, FieldName, FieldValue) VALUES (1, '9', 'P');
INSERT INTO @temp (AttImportID, FieldName, FieldValue) VALUES (1, '10', 'P');
INSERT INTO @temp (AttImportID, FieldName, FieldValue) VALUES (1, 'TotalP', '21');
INSERT INTO @temp (AttImportID, FieldName, FieldValue) VALUES (1, 'TotalPH', '26');  


--drop cached TempCacheTable if exists and create new
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempCacheTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TempCacheTable;
CREATE TABLE [#TempCacheTable] ( [Index] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL ) 

DECLARE @fName nvarchar(30), @val nvarchar(30);
DECLARE @columns nvarchar(max) = '', @col nvarchar(max) = '', @sql varchar(max) = '', @valStr nvarchar(max) = '';
DECLARE @first bit = 1, @counter int = 0;

--create cursor to loop through @TempTable
        DECLARE Column_Cur CURSOR
            FOR SELECT FieldName, FieldValue FROM @temp WHERE AttImportID = 1;

            OPEN Column_Cur;
                FETCH NEXT FROM Column_Cur INTO @fName, @val;
                    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                    BEGIN

                        --set the dynamic column
                        IF @first = 1 BEGIN                         
                            SET @col = '[' + @fName + '] nvarchar(20)';
                            SET @columns = '[' + @fName + ']';
                            SET @valStr = '''' + @val + '''';
                            SET @first = 0;
                        END ELSE BEGIN                          
                            SET @col = @col + ', [' + @fName + '] nvarchar(20)';
                            SET @columns = @columns + ', ' + '[' + @fName + ']';
                            SET @valStr = @valStr + ', ''' + @val + '''';
                        END                                     

                      -- break cursor after all 12 columns
                       IF @counter = 12 BEGIN
                          BREAK;
                       END
                        SET @counter = @counter + 1;                    

                        FETCH NEXT FROM Column_Cur INTO @fName, @val;
                    END

            CLOSE Column_Cur;
        DEALLOCATE Column_Cur;

SELECT @sql = 'ALTER TABLE #TempCacheTable ADD ' + @col
--execute to apply the change to #TempCacheTable
EXEC(@sql);    

SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO #TempCacheTable (' + @columns + ') VALUES (' + @valStr + '); 
SELECT * FROM #TempCacheTable;';
EXEC(@sql);

--drop cached TempCacheTable if exists and create new
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempCacheTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TempCacheTable;
```

So you just have to create a second cursor, in which you make the inserts for each row, based on the first cursor, and it will give you what you want.

Comment: some help available here  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44274/Transpose-a-DataTable-using-C

Comment: i am getting error  Msg 2705, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'TotalP' in table '#TempCacheTable' is specified more than once.

Comment: we can't put hard code totalPh , this field can any thing but we can use select distinct  GroupRows=   FieldName from AttImportDetail where AttImportID =1

Comment: Well since the column names repeat, that's why that error comes. Just stop after that column the cursor. If you can't stop by column name, but the amount of coulmns stays always the same, you could use a counter as stop. (Count till all columns than stop). And apply the columns. After that create another cursor, and collect the data for each row in a variable, and insert this after each circle. When all data is inserted you can just select all the data from the TempCacheTable.

Comment: i am very week in cursor , i have written same code above , can you check it. just i am getting problem assigning data in for( i=0 ........) in loop

Comment: I updated the code, so this is a working sample, you should be able to figure out the rest. I won't write all your Code!

Answer (score 0):

i did through C# code

```
// select FieldName,FieldValue from AttImportDetail where AttImportID =1
    private DataTable GenerateTransposedTable(DataTable inputTable)
    {
        DataTable outputTable = new DataTable();

        DataTable distinct = inputTable.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "FieldName"); // get unique column name

        int Columns = distinct.Rows.Count; // get unique column count 
        int rows = inputTable.Rows.Count / distinct.Rows.Count; // count no of rows

        //  create datatable with unique column name 
        foreach (DataRow inRow in distinct.Rows)
        {
            string newColName = inRow[0].ToString();
            outputTable.Columns.Add(newColName);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            DataRow newRow = outputTable.NewRow();
            for (int c = 0; c < outputTable.Columns.Count; c++)
            {
                int rowsCount = i*outputTable.Columns.Count + c;
                string colValue = inputTable.Rows[rowsCount]["FieldValue"].ToString();
                string FieldName = inputTable.Rows[rowsCount]["FieldName"].ToString();
                newRow[FieldName] = colValue;
            }
            outputTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }
        return outputTable;
    }
```